# Cutting down Stata results

Tags: linear-regression, stata

I'm running many linear regressions and probit models with a massive number of covariates. That means, every time Stata finished to compute and print the results, produce a huge list of coefficients. And, each time I have to move until the beginning of such a list, where the main coefficients are printed.

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid that. I was looking for an option to print only a certain number of lines. My sencond try was running the regression using `-quietly-` option and then trying to print a given number of lines. But I'm not really familiar with Stata. I usually work in **R**, but I have to use **Stata** this time, that's why I'm struggling with this commercial software.

For linear regressions the `-areg-` function offers a partial solution for my issue, but that function only allows me to "absorb" a single factor variable. But I need to absorb more variables and also run  probit models. Hence, `-areg-` don't work to me.

Anyone has a trick to solve this? Only print a selection of covariates in Stata?

**UPDATE:**

A minimal example: I have the following linear regression with many places and time units as FEs.

```
regress depVar Var1 Var2-Var15 i.place i.time [pw = myweigth], cluster(ID)
```

I'm interested on see only the coefficients of `Var*`. But every time I run the regression I got thousands of coefficients for the FEs.

I posted the same question on reddit, and I got the following comments:

https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/fwtds4/cutting_down_stata_results/

What is pretty much what I was looking for. Basically, is solved via `estout` package, and its `-estout-` and `-esttab-` functions:

```
estout myRegression: quietly ///
 regress depVar Var1 Var2-Var15 i.place i.time [pw = myweigth], cluster(ID)
esttab myRegression, drop(place time)
```

Maybe someone can enrich this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/fwtds4/cutting_down_stata_results/ It is a good idea to tell people about cross-posting. You got some good advice there; conversely, this is not a good question for SO without any data example or attempt at code.

Comment: Yes @NickCox, I will post the link to the answers I got there. Really, I copy-pasted this post in reddit after this post, because I have more "faith" in this community. Surprisingly, I got answers there before. I skipped the minimal-example-code intentionally this time, cause I thought it might not help. I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: Thanks for your comments about the community here, but we have not encouraged strategic questions this broad. I don't think this matches SO guidelines.